# How to retrieve all url-s for files in a google drive folder in a react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a react app. The website is quite simple and it will eventually include a gallery.

I was thinking of possible ways to make gallery updates simple for the 'owner' without creating a built-in CMS - at which point I decided to attempt using Google Drive as one.

So the goal is to make it work in a way that when you upload new images to a drive folder then they get automatically rendered in the gallery. **PS:** The goal is to avoid using libraries as much as possible!

However, I can't seem to find an answer on how to do it. I imagine that I need to somehow fetch all the URLs of the drive images at once and then map them into the gallery.

Is it possible to fetch the URLs in question with ReactJS alone? How? Does one need to use node or other backend method to do so?

Answer (score 2):

The framework you are using on the front end (React) isn't entirely relevant to what you're trying to achieve.

What you are looking for is the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference) - which you can access with a [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) request.

Now, although I've never used this API myself, looking through it briefly, it appears what you're attempting to do *may* be possible (see the [list files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) reference).

```
const request = await fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files", {
    // Authorisation and relevant parameters go here.
});

// This will retrieve the JSON response from the drive API.
const data = await request.json();
console.log(data);
```

Have a play around!